# python GPU based batch-wised dot product

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba, dot-product

I have two different big numpy array, almost (200k by 5k) and (5k by 150k)(they are not predefined array in some files, I have to extract them according to some algorithms). I need to calculate their dot product. Calculating the dot product using `np.dot` on CPU is really slow, also I have a 4GB GPU so they don't fit in GPU.
I was wondering, is there any straightforward solution in python to calculate dot product batch(block)-wised in GPU?

I have tried lots of solutions and topics. For example different `matmul` functions from `numba` produces wrong answers. 
https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/examples.html
http://jiajiamomomo.blogspot.com/2017/04/running-numba-example-of-matrix.html

I am using numpy 1.16 on windows OS. According to `np.show_config()` result, it has `mkl` support.

Comment: What dtype does the arrays have? (The Blas backend is only used on floats)

Comment: @max9111 it's float

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/nikulukani/pycublasxt The CudaBlasXt Library should be exactly fit your needs.